how to reset password wazuh in docker
I'm following the official Wazuh documentation to reset the admin and kibanaserver passwords for my Wazuh installation running in Docker. Here's a summary of what I have done and the issue I am facing:
Steps I followed:
Generated New Password Hash: I used the following command to generate new password hashes for admin and kibanaserver users:
docker run --rm -ti wazuh/wazuh-indexer:4.9.2 bash /usr/share/wazuh-indexer/plugins/opensearch-security/tools/hash.sh

This successfully generated the hash, which I updated in the docker-compose.yml file for both users.
Update Configuration: I replaced the passwords in the docker-compose.yml file with the newly generated hashes for admin and kibanaserver.
Run securityadmin.sh Script: I then ran the securityadmin.sh script with the following command to apply the changes:
\docker exec -it single-node_wazuh.indexer_1 bash -c "/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/plugins/opensearch-security/tools/securityadmin.sh \ \-cd /usr/share/wazuh-indexer/opensearch-security/ \ \-nhnv -cacert /usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin-ca.pem \ \-cert /usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin.pem \ \-key /usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin-key.pem \ \-p 9200\

Issue Encountered
When running the command, I receive the following error:
'\\\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\* This tool will be deprecated in the next major release of OpenSearch \*\*
\*\* https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/issues/1755           \*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\`
`\/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/plugins/opensearch-security/tools/securityadmin.sh: line 31: which: command not found WARNING: nor OPENSEARCH_JAVA_HOME nor JAVA_HOME is set, will use\

What I Tried:
Missing which command: The error message suggests that the which command is missing in the container. I understand that this might not be critical, but I’m unsure how to resolve this and if it affects the functionality.
Missing Java Environment Variables: The script also warns about missing JAVA_HOME and OPENSEARCH_JAVA_HOME. I don’t know if this is critical, and I have not set these variables inside the container.
Questions:
Is it safe to ignore the which command error? Will it affect the functionality of the securityadmin.sh script?
How do I resolve the missing Java environment variable warning? Should I install Java inside the Docker container, or can I proceed without setting JAVA_HOME?
Are there any other potential issues I should be aware of while using the securityadmin.sh script in a Docker environment?
Environment:

Docker Wazuh version: 4.9.2
Docker Compose used for deployment

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated

Please format your question properly.
